# How do i write VBA script to calculate the ratio between 2 columns in a spreadsheet and put it on a 3rd one?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to calculate the ratio between the values in 2 columns and put it to a 3rd column of my spreadsheet.

I am unable to figure out how do I write it over a loop in a macro and what function to use there.

I have values in columns A and B. I am trying to pull the ratio of the 2 columns in the column C, it should contain A/B.

This is what I did.

```
Sub Engagement_Ratio()

    Range("Z1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Engaged User Rate"
    Range("Z2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-12]/RC[-15])"
    Range("Z2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Z2:Z154")
    Range("Z2:Z154").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27

End Sub
```

How do I make the range of cells dynamic? so that it does it only for the range of cells that have values. How do I put something like a count on it.

Comment: Why not show something (or ANYTHING) that you have already tried?

Comment: Why use VBA for this over a formula?

Comment: I have already written some VB scripts to change the format and delete some columns, wanted to add to it, to get all things done at a single go

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
Sub Engagement_Ratio()

    Range("Z1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Engaged User Rate"
    Range("Z2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-12]/RC[-15])"
    Range("Z2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Z2:Z154")
    Range("Z2:Z154").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27

End Sub
```

How do I make the range of cells dynamic? so that it does it only for the range of cells that have values. How do I put something like a count on it.

Comment: I want only those to be calculated which have values in RC[-12] greater than 0 and sort the table according to the final value in the ratio column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column A is populated to the bottom of your data:

```
Sub Test2()

Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=[A1]).Row
Range("Z1").Value = "Engaged User Rate"
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 14).Value > 0 Then Cells(i, 26).Value = Cells(i, 14).Value / Cells(i, 11).Value
Next i
ActiveSheet.sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Z2:Z" + CStr(LastRow)) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal 'sort by sort code
With ActiveSheet.sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:Z" + CStr(LastRow))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Was it able to also solve the problem of putting in the correct ratios?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong post. It did not sort the columns or calculate the values on the engaged user rate column(Z) :(

Comment: Is it putting any numbers into column Z?  Is there something in column A all the way down to the bottom of your data?

Comment: The code you posted is not giving anything in Column Z. The code I posted did but Z154 is a random hard coded value, I wanted to make it dynamic using count of rows from column A

Comment: This code is able to adjust to any number of rows, as long as A is your determining column.  Are the two columns that you're wanting to perform calculations on N and K?  So column Z should equal N / K ?

Comment: Great!  Would you like to go ahead and accept this answer as a solution?